# Different colors for different value ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two arrays, `t` and `x`, `t` is the independent variable and `x` is computed as a function of `t`.

I can plot them easily, e.g.,

```
from pylab import *
t = linspace(o, 2*pi, 201)
x = sin(t)
plot(t, x)
```

but what I'd like is different, because in my field when `abs(x)>0.9` the probability of failure increases from 0.000001% to 99.999999% I'd like to plot in bright red the parts of the curve where I have the probable failure of my system.

I can imagine two possible solutions.

- plot two masked arrays
- play tricks with color maps

but I don't know if there are different, better possibilities and however I don't know how to implement a solution...

Comment: [Edit: wrongly pressed enter before finishing; edit2: removed the np. since you already imported *] One quick and dirty solution is to add a second plot on top of the one you already did, by exploiting that matplotlib won't plot nan values: after the 4 lines you wrote (where I assumed that `o=0` ;-) ) you can add: `t[abs(x) < 0.9] = nan; plot(t, x, 'r')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib's `plot` function does not support colormaps. This leaves us with option "plot two masked arrays" - which is a good one.

The easiest option is to plot a new line on top of the complete plot which only contains the points that satisfy a condition.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.abs(np.cumsum(np.random.rand(100)-0.5))/4.
y1 = np.copy(y)
y1[y1 < 0.7] = np.nan

plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=1.4)
plt.plot(x,y1, linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]